# Community specific site icons are not displaying in top of the sites in mobile web view

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, icons

In the mobile web view, the community specific icons are not displaying in the top, before the site names except the Stack Overflow.

The Stack Overflow icon is displaying on it's site and for the remaining sites the Stack Exchange icon only displaying.

Screenshot taken from SO and DBA:

[image: SO Mobile web view with it's icon]    [image: DBA mobile web view without it's icon]

So the community specific icons which are displaying in the **Your Communities** menu, can be display in the top of the page, before the site name in the mobile web view too.

[image: SE with it's icons]